# HTTP trace method enabled

Tags: security, http

I run some scans with nikto, and it tells me that HTTP trace method is enabled.
What is HTTP trace method ? And what can be insecure about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRACE` is a HTTP request method like `GET` and `POST` used for debugging. It echos back input to the user.

These websites outline insecurities: http://www.cgisecurity.com/questions/httptrace.shtml and http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/http_trace.html

Comment: *These websites outline insecurities.*